# Inserting string into stack returns random character

Tags: c, struct, stack, c-strings, function-definition

Working on pushing a string onto my stack and currently I am getting random characters ( the characters are not getting pushed on the stack because when I check afterwards my stack is empty)

here are the relevant functions and structure

```
typedef char stackitem;

struct stack {
stackitem  d;
struct stack *next;
};

typedef  struct stack ELEMENT;
typedef  ELEMENT   *POINTER;

void push(POINTER *Top, stackitem a)
/* Put item a into the top of the stack */
     {
        POINTER temp;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
        temp->d = a;
        temp->next = *Top;
        *Top = temp;
        printf("Insert element %c\n", temp->d);
     }
void push_string(POINTER *Top,char *string)
/* Push a string of characters into a stack. */
    {
        char *tmp = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
        if (tmp)
        strcpy(tmp, string);
    push(&Top,tmp);
```

Parts of the second function I found on another SO thread.
And this is how I am using it:

```
main()
    {
    POINTER top;
        top= (POINTER) NULL;
        stackitem A='A';
        stackitem B='B';
        char *C="12345";
        push_string(&top,C);
        print_stack(top);

        return 0;
   }
```

How am i able to add a string to the stack? the push function works for pushing chars onto the stack but I cant get it to push a whole string.

Comment: Apparently, your stack (whose definition you don't show) can hold chars, but not strings. One way to push a whole string onto the stack is to push all characters, so instead of trying to push `"ABC"`, loop over the string and push `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`.

Comment: ive updated my post for the definitions... wouldnt looping over the string push each character as a seperate element on the stack? this is for some uni tasks and I believe the purpose is to push a string onto the stack

Comment: It's considered a bad practice to do `typedef  ELEMENT   *POINTER;`. Use `ELEMENT*` so the reader can see it's a pointer.

Comment: Doesn't this code warn? Seems to me the compiler would have found the problem immediately! Make sure to enable your compiler's warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc/clang)

Comment: @william_ The function push_string does not make a sense.

Comment: Yes, looping would push the characters as individual elements. (Because your post wasn't very clear, I took the libery to guess that.) You can make it so that the stack accepts both strings and characters, for example with a tagged union as stack item. But then code that pops stuff off the stack must also distinguish between strings and chars. Another possibility is to turn chars into 1-letter-strings.

Comment: If you want a stack that stores only strings, you must adopt your item type. If you have several stacks that can hold different items, you need a `CharStack`, an `IntStack`, a `StringStack` and so on. C++ and many other languages let you use templates, so that you could say `stack<char>` and the compiler creates a `CharStack` for you under the hood.

Comment: Why did you remove all your code from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, turn on all warning (options `-Wall -pedantic`).
The compiler will likely complain about the casting between non-compatible types.

The function `push()` is dedicated to put a single `char` on the stack, whereas `push_string()` is dedicated to put all characters of `string` one by one.

Therefore to put a string you should put each character of the string individually.

```
void push_string(POINTER *Top,char *string) {
  for (char *s = string; *s; ++s)
    push(Top, *s);
}
```

Comment: quick question about the loop, what does the condition *s; represent?

Comment: @william_, `*s` is checking the character pointed by s. The loop continues until 0-value (string terminator) is encountered.  Value 0 is `false` in C.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet of the function push_string  as is does not make a sense.

For example there is no any need to create a copy of the passed string.

```
    char *tmp = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    if (tmp)
    strcpy(tmp, string);
```

Secondly this call

```
push(&Top,tmp);
```

has invalid types of arguments.

The function `push_string` can look the following way

```
void push_string( POINTER *Top, const char *string )
{
    for ( ; *string; ++string ) push( Top, *string );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char stackitem;

struct stack {
stackitem  d;
struct stack *next;
};

typedef  struct stack ELEMENT;
typedef  ELEMENT   *POINTER;

int push( POINTER *Top, stackitem c )
{
    POINTER temp = malloc( sizeof( ELEMENT ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        temp->d = c;
        temp->next = *Top;
        *Top = temp;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void push_string( POINTER *Top, const char *string )
{
    for ( ; *string; ++string ) push( Top, *string );
}

int pop( POINTER *Top, stackitem *c )
{
    int success = *Top != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        *c = ( *Top )->d;
        POINTER temp = *Top;
        *Top = ( *Top )->next;
        free( temp );
    }
    
    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    POINTER top = NULL;
    
    push_string( &top, "12345" );
    
    for ( char c; pop( &top, &c ); )
    {
        putchar( c );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
54321
```

Pay attention to that you should check that the memory allocation for a new node of the stack was successful.

In the demonstrative program the function `push` reports whether pushing an element was successful.

The function `push_string` also should report whether a string was pushed successfully. In this case it can be defined the following way

```
int push_string( POINTER *Top, const char *string )
{
    while ( *string && push( Top, *string ) ) ++string;
  
    return *string == '\0';
}
```

Just substitute the function `push_string` in the demonstrative program above with this one and the program will work as expected.